# low graphics mode coupled with other errors

Tags: drivers, ati, fglrx

so bugbuntu 14.04 hit me again. I upgraded my graphicscard so i thought it would be a good idea to install new drivers. I changed from a HD 5850 to a R9 280X. I took a quick look at the graphicsdriver before installing the new one and it said something along the lines of "xorg blabla (open source)" under additional drivers. So i downloaded the new driver, ran
`sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*` and installed the new driver with its installer and rebooted.

Upon reboot i got the low graphics mode error, tried reloading old config, didn't work. (The menu also severly bugged out, i always got returned to the dialog with "load old" and "reload current" with no message at all). running in low-graphics mode just caused ubuntu to hang indefinitely, same for going to terminal from there. BTW: pressing ctrl+alt+f1 there also caused it to hang.

So after some googling i tried the recovery mode, `failsafex` just led to the situation described in the paragraph before. `root` atleast brought me to console, but started with some error not being able to load /bash/XYZ and i couldn't use `apt-get` there because it always errored out saying something was missing.

So, any suggestion on how to fix this mess is highly appreciated :)

Comment: Yeah downvote me for an accurate description of what happened. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i got help from a friend, but to no avail. The final solution was to reinstall ubuntu. Which, as always with linux, lead to a whole bunch of other problems, but luckily we solved most of them.